# Lighting Keyframes Not Saving

Tags: keyframes, lighting

Recently I've had an issue with my light in a scene. Basically, I have a point light that is parented to my character so that it follows the character around. I have set the emission strength to 0 at the first keyframe, and I then change it to a strength of 4 in the next keyframe. This is done because I only need the light active for a certain time in the animation. However, once I've set this keyframe, performing any other action will bring it back down to 0. For example, I set the keyframe to a strength of 4, move forward one frame, then the strength resets back to 0.

I can provide pictures if need be, but I think I've explained it well enough. Is there another way I could do this? Or is there some fix that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the keyframe again, after you've changed the value, or just changed the value?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. It would be great if you include the blend file or upload a video of what's actually happening with the scene. I believe there might be some settings that have been changed thus causing you this problem

Comment: @lemon Hey, thanks for the answer. I relaunched Blender, deleted the keyframes, and set them again as you've described. Somehow that managed to work. Before I was adding the keyframe, THEN changing the value.

Of course it's something as simple as this!

Comment: @RileySpencer, you can also turn "auto keying" on if easier. This is the round button in the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere and couldn't find an answer that helped. My workaround was to encapsulate the light within a sphere and animate the sphere, for example let's say the sphere you have made around the light to block it out is scale 1,1,1 keep it this way until you need the light to come on then change the scale of the sphere to 0,0,0, bam lights on. It's the only thing that ended up working for me! : ) good luck!